# Break Data out of one column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, etl

I have a table full of attendance data for students, we are migrating to another student info system and the way they want the flat files to be is one row for each student for each day with all 7 periods listed out. Right now our data is stored as one record per day per period (see attached schema) What would be the best way to format this data to match what I have listed above. I'm also attaching a screenshot of how they want it (each row is a column).

**Added screen shot of data.**

[image: Our current Database Schema]

[image: What it needs to be]

[image]

Comment: I'm totally confused by your question. You said they want "all 7 periods" listed out. I do not see periods in your schema... I see absent_period. I also see there are move than 7 Abs Code Period. I see Abs Code Period 1 thru Abs Code Period 14. It would be very helpful if you gave an example using real data not just the schema and layout.

Comment: I added a screen shot of the data. There are more than 7 periods to accommodate for other schools we only have 7 sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so pivot was not what I needed. I ended up talking to a colleuge about my problem and he told me to use subqueries. So this is how I solved it!

```
select distinct student_id,school_year,school_number,absent_date,
(select absent_code from attend_student_detail a2 where a2.student_id=a.student_id and a2.absent_date=a.absent_date and a2.absent_period='H') as daily_code,
(select absent_code from attend_student_detail a2 where a2.student_id=a.student_id and a2.absent_date=a.absent_date and a2.absent_period='1') as per_1,
(select absent_code from attend_student_detail a2 where a2.student_id=a.student_id and a2.absent_date=a.absent_date and a2.absent_period='2') as per_2,
(select absent_code from attend_student_detail a2 where a2.student_id=a.student_id and a2.absent_date=a.absent_date and a2.absent_period='3') as per_3,
(select absent_code from attend_student_detail a2 where a2.student_id=a.student_id and a2.absent_date=a.absent_date and a2.absent_period='4') as per_4,
(select absent_code from attend_student_detail a2 where a2.student_id=a.student_id and a2.absent_date=a.absent_date and a2.absent_period='5') as per_5,
(select absent_code from attend_student_detail a2 where a2.student_id=a.student_id and a2.absent_date=a.absent_date and a2.absent_period='6') as per_6,
(select absent_code from attend_student_detail a2 where a2.student_id=a.student_id and a2.absent_date=a.absent_date and a2.absent_period='7') as per_7 

FROM attend_student_detail a

Order By Absent_Date, Student_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at PIVOT and UNPIVOT.

[Here](http://www.sql-programmers.com/using-pivot-and-unpivot.aspx) is an example

Comment: Looks interesting, gonna have to study this figure out how to apply it to my situation.

Comment: From reading that article, it almost seems like I need a combination of the two? Because I don't need to aggregate the attendance. I think A good example of what I need is say I'm taking todays attendance and I have a student that is absent I would see only one line with 7 different period columns and each would have the absent code in those columns. I think I need to use a case statement somehow but I need only on date line per student per day? Thoughts?